# Access arrays inside an array with a parse inside

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [tag] => EPP
                [type] => open
                [level] => 1
                [attributes] => Array
                    (
                        [XMLNS] => urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0
                    )

                [value] => 

            )


.
.
.

        [35] => Array
            (
                [tag] => DOMAIN:HOSTNAME
                [type] => complete
                [level] => 7
                [value] => ns1.domain.net
            )

.
.
.

        [40] => Array
            (
                [tag] => DOMAIN:HOSTNAME
                [type] => complete
                [level] => 7
                [value] => ns2.domain.net
            )

    )
```

I want to get the value of `value` key of all arrays inside this array where have a `[tag] => DOMAIN:HOSTNAME` inside.
I tried to do this with `array_colum($array, 'DOMAIN:HOSTNAME');` which returns an empty array. I want to have an array like this finally:

```
['ns1.domain.net', 'ns2.domain.net']
```

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Did you start by writing a simple foreach loop over the array? I would have started there

Comment: What does _“with a parse inside”_ mean …?

Comment: A simple foreach loop, or [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/array_filter) and [`array_map`](https://secure.php.net/array_map), could achieve that.

Comment: Did this start of as XML and mangled into an array.

Comment: @NigelRen yes this was a xml first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `array_walk` and references?

```
$hostnames = [];
array_walk($your_array, function($item) use(&$hostnames) {
    if ($item['tag'] == 'DOMAIN:HOSTNAME') {
        $hostnames[] = $item['value'];
    }
});
```

The `foreach` solution:

```
$hostnames = [];
foreach ($your_array as $item) {
    if ($item['tag'] == 'DOMAIN:HOSTNAME') {
        $hostnames[] = $item['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`array_walk`](https://secure.php.net/array_walk) instead. `array_map` creates a new array from the return values.

Comment: This works fine and array_map works either. why array_walk is better?

Comment: @ehsan The `array_map` is designed to apply function and return value. The `array_walk` is designed just to apply the function, and thanks to this, theoretically, it might be a bit faster than `array_map`. Moreover, in terms of “semantics” the `array_walk` fits better in this case. By the way, use `foreach` if you need a faster solution and filtering items by `$item['tag'] == 'DOMAIN:HOSTNAME'` is the only thing you need (see my update).

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(array(
    "tag" => "EPP",
    "type" => "open",
    "level" => "1",
    "attributes"=> 
        array("XMLNS" => "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"),
    "value" => "ns1.domain.net"),
    array(
    "tag" => "EPP",
    "type" => "open",
    "level" => "1",
    "attributes"=> 
    array("XMLNS" => "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0"),
    "value" => "ns2.domain.net"));


foreach($array as $item){
    print $item['value'] . "<br/>";
}

// output
ns1.domain.net
ns2.domain.net
```

or

```
$vals = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
  $vals[] = $value['value'];
}

print_r($vals);
//output 
Array
(
    [0] => ns1.domain.net
    [1] => ns2.domain.net
)
```

Comment: What about the filter according to tag?

Comment: This can't filter the nameservers and note this is a vary big array which I printed just a little part of. @Ashfaq